# how to fill an empty matrix with data frame values

Tags: r, matrix, casting

I am desperately trying to fill a matrix with values from a data frame. 
It is trade data, so the data frame looks something like this:

```
country1 country2 value
1 Afghanistan  Albania    30
2 Afghanistan  Albania    81
3 Afghanistan    China     5
4     Albania  Germany     6
5       China  Germany     8
6       China   Turkey   900
7     Germany   Turkey    12
8     Germany      USA     3
9     Germany   Zambia   700
```

Using the unique and sort commands I have created a list of all countries that occur in the df (and converted it to a matrix):

```
     countries_sorted
[1,] "Afghanistan"   
[2,] "Albania"       
[3,] "China"         
[4,] "Germany"       
[5,] "Turkey"        
[6,] "USA"           
[7,] "Zambia"
```

Using this "list", I have created an empty trade matrix (7x7):

```
             Afghanistan Albania China Germany Turkey USA Zambia
Afghanistan          NA      NA    NA      NA     NA  NA     NA
Albania              NA      NA    NA      NA     NA  NA     NA
China                NA      NA    NA      NA     NA  NA     NA
Germany              NA      NA    NA      NA     NA  NA     NA
Turkey               NA      NA    NA      NA     NA  NA     NA
USA                  NA      NA    NA      NA     NA  NA     NA
Zambia               NA      NA    NA      NA     NA  NA     NA
```

I am now hopelessly failing to fill this matrix with the numbers/sums from the value column of df.
I have tried something like this:

```
a<-cast(df, country1~country2 , sum)
```

which works to a degree BUT the matrix does not retain its original 7x7 format, which is what I need to have a matrix where the diagonal is all 0s.

```
> a
     country1 Albania China Germany Turkey USA Zambia
1 Afghanistan     111     5       0      0   0      0
2     Albania       0     0       6      0   0      0
3       China       0     0       8    900   0      0
4     Germany       0     0       0     12   3    700
```

Please, anyone with a solution????

Answer (score 4):

Starting with these 2 data sets:

```
#your data.frame
df <- read.table(header=T, file='clipboard', stringsAsFactors = F)
#the list of unique countries
countries <- unique(c(df$country1,df$country2))
```

You could do:

```
#create all the country combinations
newdf <- expand.grid(countries, countries)
#change names
colnames(newdf) <- c('country1', 'country2')
#add a value of 0 for the new combinations (won't affect outcome)
newdf$value <- 0
#row bind with original dataset
df2 <- rbind(df, newdf)


#and create the table using xtabs:
#the aggregate function will create the sum of the value for each combination
> xtabs(value ~ country1 + country2, aggregate(value~country1+country2,df2,sum))
             country2
country1      Afghanistan Albania China Germany Turkey USA Zambia
  Afghanistan           0     111     5       0      0   0      0
  Albania               0       0     0       6      0   0      0
  China                 0       0     0       8    900   0      0
  Germany               0       0     0       0     12   3    700
  Turkey                0       0     0       0      0   0      0
  USA                   0       0     0       0      0   0      0
  Zambia                0       0     0       0      0   0      0
```

Comment: I liked the clever approach of `rbind` (with 0 `value`) instead of joining data frames. Could be faster when there are more data, right?

Comment: @AntoniosK Hmmm `rbind` has a bad reputation in terms of effectiveness because of the copy-on-modify semantics (requires more memory and makes it slower). The `left_join` function you re using from `dplyr` is definitely more efficient. Now in terms of speed, in this case I am rbinding just two data.frames so I am not really certain which one is going to be faster (probably `left_join`) but `dplyr` will be more efficient when there are limitations with RAM. Kai kali mas mera Antwni :)

Comment: Great. Good to know @LyzandeR. (Twra me koufanes! Kali mas mera file...)

Comment: @AntoniosK Etsi kanw kai ksafniazw ton kosmo haha. Kali synexeia :)

Comment: @yzandeR: Thanks for the quick answer! I tried it out and it works PERFECTLY for this sample data...Unfortunately in the real world, when I try to rbind, I get the following error:                                       Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match                             How do I fix that?

Comment: The two files need to have exactly the same number of columns and the same column names as well. The error implies that one of your data frames has more than three columns so just make a new data.frame with the columns you need.

Comment: Thank you for that! It worked all the way, without errors! The table looks great and the sums of the values are correct!
Unfortunatety I still have the problem that the final matrix/table/data frame is NOT row=col.... For some reason some columns (country2) are left out....

Comment: I can't say what's wrong unless I see the data and code I 'm afraid... Having a data.frame like df2 (including same column names) should make the xtabs work in any situation. Check maybe you got the column names wrong. Or maybe you didn't include all of the unique countries in the countries vector.

Comment: Ay ay ay... Thank you either way! I will try my best to get this last step to work... maybe just add the 4 missing columns manually.... sigh....
You helped me out big time though! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

And an alternative solution, to @LyzandeR 's great answer, using `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

```
dt = read.table(text=
"country1 country2 value
Afghanistan  Albania    30
Afghanistan  Albania    81
Afghanistan    China     5
Albania  Germany     6
China  Germany     8
China   Turkey   900
Germany   Turkey    12
Germany      USA     3
Germany   Zambia   700", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 = 
    dt %>% 
      group_by(country1,country2) %>%    # for every combination of countries
      summarise(SumValue = sum(value))   # get the sum of value

# get all possible countries that appear in your dataset
list_countries = union(dt2$country1, dt2$country2)

expand.grid(country1=list_countries, country2=list_countries, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%  # create all possible combinations of countries
  left_join(dt2, by=c("country1","country2")) %>%  # join back info whenever it is found
  mutate(SumValue = ifelse(is.na(SumValue),0,SumValue)) %>%  # replace NAs with 0s
  spread(country2,SumValue)  # reshape data

#     country1 Afghanistan Albania China Germany Turkey USA Zambia
# 1 Afghanistan           0     111     5       0      0   0      0
# 2     Albania           0       0     0       6      0   0      0
# 3       China           0       0     0       8    900   0      0
# 4     Germany           0       0     0       0     12   3    700
# 5      Turkey           0       0     0       0      0   0      0
# 6         USA           0       0     0       0      0   0      0
# 7      Zambia           0       0     0       0      0   0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only an upper diagonal matrix and the diagonal is 0 it's the same except for the first column which is removed since it contains no information (only zeros). You can just add it to the matrix using cbind:

```
Z = matrix(rep(0,7),ncol=1)
newMatrix = cbind(Z,oldMatrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite late, I know, but the package `reshape2` has a dedicated function.
Taking your `data.frame` as example:

```
df_back_to_matrix <- reshape2::acast(df = your_df, formula = country1~country2, value.var = "value")
```

Note that the order of variables in the formula is important: reshape2 will read it as `row_variable ~ column_variable`